# Syntax error on request optimisation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to optimize a SQL query but I face a weird issue.

Here is my optimized request :

```
SELECT proj.ProjetId AS ProjetId,
                SUM (CASE WHEN modTrans.Code != 'FoO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS  VAL1,
                SUM(CASE WHEN modTrans.Code = 'Foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS  VAL2
    FROM Projet.Projet proj
        INNER JOIN Workflow.PointControle ptCont 
            ON ptCont.ProjetId = proj.ProjetId
        INNER JOIN Workflow.PointControleModele ptContMod 
            ON ptContMod.PointControleModeleId = ptCont.PointControleModeleId
        INNER JOIN Commande.CommandeTAC cdeTAC
            ON cdeTAC.ProjetId = proj.ProjetId
        INNER JOIN Commande.CommandeTACCatalogue cdeTACCat
            ON cdeTACCat.CommandeTACId = cdeTAC.CommandeTACId
        INNER JOIN Fournisseur.Fournisseur four
            ON four.FournisseurId = cdeTACCat.FournisseurId
        INNER JOIN Fournisseur.ModeTransmission modTrans
            ON modTrans.ModeTransmissionId = four.ModeTransmissionId
    WHERE ptContMod.PointControleModeleCode = 'FFooooooooo'
        AND ptCont.Etat = 'Foooooo'
        AND proj.DateLivraison IS NOT NULL
        AND [proj].[DateLivraison] <= DATEADD(DAY, 14, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY proj.ProjetId
    HAVING COUNT(VAL1) > 0 AND COUNT(VAL2) = 0
```

I got this error :

> Column name invalid : 'VAL1' Column name invalid : 'VAL2'

The error is in the HAVING section.
After reading this documentation I dont undestand why there is an error because I respect the syntax : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

You can find the unoptimized complete request here :

```
BEGIN
    WITH Trans(VAL1, VAL2, projetId) AS
    (
        SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN modTrans.Code != 'Foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  NbNonSALM
                , SUM(CASE WHEN modTrans.Code = 'Foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS  NbSALM
                , proj.ProjetId AS projetId
        FROM Projet.Projet proj
        INNER JOIN Workflow.PointControle ptCont 
            ON ptCont.ProjetId = proj.ProjetId
        INNER JOIN Workflow.PointControleModele ptContMod 
            ON ptContMod.PointControleModeleId = ptCont.PointControleModeleId
        INNER JOIN Commande.CommandeTAC cdeTAC
            ON cdeTAC.ProjetId = proj.ProjetId
        INNER JOIN Commande.CommandeTACCatalogue cdeTACCat
            ON cdeTACCat.CommandeTACId = cdeTAC.CommandeTACId
        INNER JOIN Fournisseur.Fournisseur four
            ON four.FournisseurId = cdeTACCat.FournisseurId
        INNER JOIN Fournisseur.ModeTransmission modTrans
            ON modTrans.ModeTransmissionId = four.ModeTransmissionId
        WHERE ptContMod.PointControleModeleCode = 'Foooooo'
            AND ptCont.Etat = 'Fooo'
            AND proj.DateLivraison IS NOT NULL
            AND DATEADD(DAY, -14, proj.DateLivraison) <= GETDATE()
        GROUP BY proj.ProjetId  
    )

    SELECT proj.ProjetId AS ProjetId
    FROM Projet.Projet proj
        INNER JOIN Workflow.PointControle ptCont 
            ON ptCont.ProjetId = proj.ProjetId
        INNER JOIN Workflow.PointControleModele ptContMod 
            ON ptContMod.PointControleModeleId = ptCont.PointControleModeleId
        INNER JOIN Commande.CommandeTAC cdeTAC
            ON cdeTAC.ProjetId = proj.ProjetId
        INNER JOIN Commande.CommandeTACCatalogue cdeTACCat
            ON cdeTACCat.CommandeTACId = cdeTAC.CommandeTACId
        INNER JOIN Fournisseur.Fournisseur four
            ON four.FournisseurId = cdeTACCat.FournisseurId
        INNER JOIN Fournisseur.ModeTransmission modTrans
            ON modTrans.ModeTransmissionId = four.ModeTransmissionId
        INNER JOIN Trans ON Trans.projetId = proj.ProjetId
    WHERE ptContMod.PointControleModeleCode = 'Foo'
        AND ptCont.Etat = 'Fooo'
        AND proj.DateLivraison IS NOT NULL
        AND DATEADD(DAY, -14, proj.DateLivraison) <= GETDATE()
    GROUP BY proj.ProjetId
    HAVING COUNT(trans.NbNonSALM) > 0 AND COUNT(trans.NbSALM) = 0

    UNION

    SELECT projet.ProjetId AS ProjetId
    FROM Projet.Projet projet
        INNER JOIN Workflow.PointControle ptControle 
                ON ptControle.ProjetId = projet.ProjetId
        INNER JOIN Workflow.PointControleModele ptContMod 
                ON ptContMod.PointControleModeleId = ptControle.PointControleModeleId
        INNER JOIN Commande.CommandeTAC cdeTAC
                ON cdeTAC.ProjetId = projet.ProjetId
        INNER JOIN Commande.CommandeTACCatalogue cdeTACCat
                ON cdeTACCat.CommandeTACId = cdeTAC.CommandeTACId
        INNER JOIN commande.AREntete arEnt
                ON arEnt.ProjetIdTAC = cdeTAC.ProjetIdTAC
        INNER JOIN Commande.Article art
                ON art.AREnteteId = arEnt.AREnteteId AND art.CommandeTACCatalogueId = cdeTACCat.CommandeTACCatalogueId
        INNER JOIN Fournisseur.Fournisseur four
                ON four.FournisseurId = cdeTACCat.FournisseurId
        INNER JOIN Fournisseur.ModeTransmission modTrans
                ON modTrans.ModeTransmissionId = four.ModeTransmissionId
    WHERE ptContMod.PointControleModeleCode = 'Fooo'
        AND ptControle.Etat = 'Foo'
        AND arEnt.SuppressionLogique = 0
        AND arEnt.Statut IS NOT NULL
        AND arEnt.Statut >= 4
        AND arEnt.Statut != 9
        AND modTrans.Code = 'Fooooooo'
        AND projet.SiteId = @siteId
END
;
```

Comment: You cannot refer to an alias in the `Having` clause, either repeat what you have in the `Select` or use a CTE/Subquery. The HAVING clause is evaluated before the SELECT - so the server doesn't yet know about that alias. http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/sql/node22.html

Comment: My first optimization was to mixed the two same request in one. I think about changing the date condition too and use more index on inner join

Comment: VAL1 and VAL2 in your query are never going to be NULL, so both COUNT(VAL1) and COUNT(VAL2) will *always* be greater than 0. What is the point then of your HAVING clause? Did you perhaps meant SUM(VAL1) and SUM(VAL2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not try this, but I think it work for you.. Or you can give some sample data if error comes.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT proj.ProjetId AS ProjetId,
                SUM (CASE WHEN modTrans.Code != 'FoO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)    AS  VAL1,
                SUM(CASE WHEN modTrans.Code = 'Foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  AS  VAL2
    FROM Projet.Projet proj
        INNER JOIN Workflow.PointControle ptCont 
            ON ptCont.ProjetId = proj.ProjetId
        INNER JOIN Workflow.PointControleModele ptContMod 
            ON ptContMod.PointControleModeleId = ptCont.PointControleModeleId
        INNER JOIN Commande.CommandeTAC cdeTAC
            ON cdeTAC.ProjetId = proj.ProjetId
        INNER JOIN Commande.CommandeTACCatalogue cdeTACCat
            ON cdeTACCat.CommandeTACId = cdeTAC.CommandeTACId
        INNER JOIN Fournisseur.Fournisseur four
            ON four.FournisseurId = cdeTACCat.FournisseurId
        INNER JOIN Fournisseur.ModeTransmission modTrans
            ON modTrans.ModeTransmissionId = four.ModeTransmissionId
    WHERE ptContMod.PointControleModeleCode = 'FFooooooooo'
        AND ptCont.Etat = 'Foooooo'
        AND proj.DateLivraison IS NOT NULL
        AND [proj].[DateLivraison] <= DATEADD(DAY, 14, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY proj.ProjetId
) 
SELECT ProjetId, VAL1, VAL2
FROM CTE 
GROUP BY ProjetId, VAL1, VAL2
HAVING COUNT(VAL1) > 0 AND COUNT(VAL2) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the alias in the `HAVING` clause. Replace with this instead:

```
HAVING 
    SUM(CASE WHEN modTrans.Code != 'FoO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 
    AND SUM(CASE WHEN modTrans.Code = 'Foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: With your sample the request works but doesn't return the same result as the first long request (that I haven't shown)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `HAVING` clause with this

```
HAVING
SUM (CASE WHEN modTrans.Code != 'FoO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0
AND
SUM(CASE WHEN modTrans.Code = 'Foo' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=0
```

Comment: With your sample the request works but doesn't return the same result as the first long request (that I haven't shown)

Comment: I just edited my first post. Anyway thank for having take a look